# Pull signal low using a pic microcontroller

Tags: pic, signal, gsm

I'm working with a [ADH8066 GSM Module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10138) and a [PIC16F688](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41203E.pdf).  I want to reset the ADH8066 using the ON_KEY pin which is described as:

```
Power On/OFF signal. Effective at low. Required 100ms above power level.
```

The way that I read this is that in order to reset the GSM module, I need to pull the signal low for at least 100ms to reset, and I have confirmed this through testing.  My question is, what is the best way to pull the signal low (i.e. connect to ground) using my PIC16F688?  My first thought is to use a NPN transistor with the base connected to the PIC and the ADH8066 ON_KEY pin connected to through the collector/emitter to ground.  Is this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADH8066 may have an inbuilt resistor that is a pull-up to it's supply voltage. You'll need to understand if this is so and if not you'll need to apply one. Then use an NPN BJT with emitter to 0V / ground. Connect the collector to the on/off pin on the ADH8066 and connect the base (via a 10k resistor) to the PIC pin you want tu use for controlling on/off.

A high coming from the PIC pin will cause the NPN to switch on and pull the relevant GSM module's pin to ground/0V. A low on the PIC pin will turn off the NPN and the external pull-up (or internal) will pull the module's control pin to Vcc.

Comment: Thank you!  When powered on, the ADH8066 has a 3.3V signal on the ON_KEY pin, so I assume this is coming from an internal pull-up resistor.  Also, I'm curious how you came up with the value 10K for the NPN's base resistor?

Comment: 10k or 1k will do. To turn on a half decent NPN you'll need about 1 mA for light loads and 10mA for heavier loads (this is a big generalism of course but for the type of load this pin will likely have 10k should work and if it doesn't then lower the base resistor to 1k and repeat. Almost without doubt 1k will work. Also try a 1k resistor as the pull-up on the pin.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what voltage you are running the PIC at.  If it's connected to the same power supply as the module, then just connect the ONKEY input of the module directly to a PIC output pin.

If the PIC is running at a different voltage, then using a NPN transistor makes sense.  I didn't look, but I'm assuming that this ONKEY input only requires a rather small current to pull it low.  In that case, you don't need any external part other than the transistor:

[image]

Use a PIC pin with a weak internal pullup, which is shown above as R1.  Never drive the output high.  Either drive it low or let the pullup weakly drive it high.  The current from the pullup will be amplified by the transistor, which should allow it to sink enough current from ONKEY to bring it solidly low.

Comment: Both the pic and the GSM module are being driven from the same power source, but each has it's own voltage regulator.  The pic is running at 5V and the ADH8066 is running at 3.3V.  Given this, it sounds like I need to use a transistor to pull the ON_KEY low.